# Magento extension to calculate measurement and other options

Tags: magento-1.7, extensions

Is there a Magento extension to calculate blinds size and total price?

Something like Choose:

1. SET YOUR MEASUREMENT:
   cm, mm, inches

-width
-height

2. CHOOSE ADN SCALLOP

-Select your Shape/Scallop 
-Do you want eyelets?

3. CHOOSE CONTROLS
   -something
   -something

Comment: If you only have a limited number of sizes available, I'd think an extension would be overkill. How detailed are customers able to get when choosing sizes?

Answer (score 1):

Have not tried this, but there is an extension for CSV sized 2D products called [Magento CSV Based Pricing Extension](http://www.magentopricing.com/csv-dimension-length-width-variation-extension/) . The other features would probably require custom development. This extension allows you to sell items like blinds, liquids, barrels, wall paper, coverings, windows and other variable sized products. You are able to define your own pricing structure by using a CSV file rather than using a fixed price option in Magento. Users can select dimensions such as length & width on product page and the price will be calculated based on this input.

Comment: Can you provide some details about what the extension does? Single link answers are not the best answers and might get deleted.

Comment: i found this extension as well [link]http://demo.micosolutions.com/cmp/custom-math-pricing/software-pricing-example.html but it needs customization more . is there some checkout where i can add each option in another step? so width - 1 step , colour - 2 step. i want the step to be with AJAX shopping cart so dont go to another page between steps.